# Get count of ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `images` - foo_id isn't a key, can have more than one row with the same number.
How do I count the rows with different values for foo_id?

images:

```
id (int) | foo_id (int) | ...
```

Example:

```
0 | 1 | ...
0 | 2 | ...
0 | 3 | ...
0 | 1 | ...
```

Wanted result:
**3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT foo_id) FROM images
```

Also see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp, several variants of the `COUNT` statement (including the `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` syntax you need in your case are described there)

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ..) instead SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) - well. Thank you, will be accepted asap.

Comment: Happy to help :) `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT` can't work because you'd select a `COUNT` first (yielding one result), and then `DISTINCT`ing it (yielding exactly the same count).